# React-- Copy to clipboard-- Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have something like this in a div

```
  <div className="generated-voucher-code-details">
                <p>Your voucher Code is <span style={{color:'#000000', fontWeight:'500'}}>“X1X1X1“</span>.</p>
                <p>To know more on how to redeem the gift card visit the link <span style={{color:'#C7417B'}}>stores.com</span></p>
                <p>Choose Preferred date, Time, Number of People and Book Now.</p>
                <p>Apply voucher code in Have a Xoxo Voucher Check Box.</p>
                <p>Pay Extra Amount if any through other mode of payments.</p>
                <p>Your order is successfully placed.</p>
                <p>You will receive confirmation within 24 hours.</p>
  </div>
```

This Div is in a box assume, below this box, I have a button.

Now, How to copy the whole text when we click on this button?

Comment: <CopyToClipboard onCopy={this.onCopy} text={this.state.value}>
                    <Button
                        style={{'background-color':'#C7417B',
                        'border-radius':'8px',
                        'color':'#FFFFFF',
                        width:'95px',
                        height:'35px',
                        fontSize:'14px'}}
                        className='large'
                        >
                        Copy Text
                    </Button>
               </CopyToClipboard>

Comment: onCopy = () => {
    this.setState({copied: true});
  };

Answer (score 1):

welcome to stack overflow.

Please check below a working code sample.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

export default function () {
   const divRef = useRef();
   const copyToCB = () => {
    const div = document.createRange();

    div.setStartBefore(divRef.current);
    div.setEndAfter(divRef.current);
    window.getSelection().empty();
    window.getSelection().addRange(div);
    document.execCommand('copy')
}
return (
    <>
        <div className="generated-voucher-code-details" ref={divRef}>
            <p>Your voucher Code is <span style={{ color: '#000000', fontWeight: '500' }}>“X1X1X1“</span>.</p>
            <p>To know more on how to redeem the gift card visit the link <span style={{ color: '#C7417B' }}>stores.com</span></p>
            <p>Choose Preferred date, Time, Number of People and Book Now.</p>
            <p>Apply voucher code in Have a Xoxo Voucher Check Box.</p>
            <p>Pay Extra Amount if any through other mode of payments.</p>
            <p>Your order is successfully placed.</p>
            <p>You will receive confirmation within 24 hours.</p>
        </div>
        <button onClick={copyToCB}>Copy to CB</button>
    </>
)
}
```

Thanks to https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-select-text-between-div-tag-using-js/4283/5

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.execCommand("copy")` to implement it.

For more details head to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).